# ABO allele frequencies: Why use the EM algorithm?

Tags: genetics, population-genetics, statistics, allele, hardy-weinberg

In textbooks and lecture notes and slides posted online, determining allele frequencies using blood type information (ABO), under the assumption of Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium, is accomplished using the EM algorithm. It seems to me, though, that this problem can be solved using basic algebra: If $a$, $b$, $o$ are the frequencies of the $A$, $B$, and $O$ alleles, respectively, and $p_A$, $p_B$, and $p_O$ are the proportions of the population in question displaying blood types $A$, $B$, and $O$, then

$$
p_A = a^2 + 2ao,\quad p_B = b^2 + 2bo,\quad\text{and}\quad p_O = o^2.
$$

Inverting the third equation gives $o$ in terms of $p_O$:

$$
o = \sqrt{p_O}.
$$

Plugging that into the first equation and rearranging, we get the quadratic equation.

$$
a^2 + 2\sqrt{p_O}a - p_A = 0
$$

Solving using the quadratic formula and throwing away the negative solution, we get

$$
a = \sqrt{p_O + p_A} - \sqrt{p_O}.
$$

Symmetrically,

$$
b = \sqrt{p_O + p_B} - \sqrt{p_O}.
$$

Thus, we've solved for the allele frequencies $a$, $b$, and $o$ with only basic algebra.

In the standard textbook case in which $p_A = fa = 186/521$, $p_B = 38/521$, and $p_O = 284/521$, this gives

$$
a \approx 0.21,\quad  b\approx0.05, \quad\text{and}\quad o\approx0.74,
$$

which is close to what you get after a few iterations of the EM algorithm.

**Question (finally):** If the above calculation is correct (if not, please let me know!), what is a "simplest" non-synthetic (real data, from the literature) example of an allele frequency computation from phenotype data that actually **requires** a sophisticated technique like the EM algorithm?